I am trying to execute a command, but the assertion error , I am working at Google colab
I find a  error is : for stylegan2 model trainig
File "/content/drive/MyDrive/stylegan2/training/dataset.py", line 53, in init
assert os.path.isdir(self.tfrecord_dir)
AssertionError
and also the path i set in my code:
tfrecord_dir    = "/content/drive/MyDrive/stylegan2/output_images",
[See hereand also](https://i.sstatic.net/Rq7Tb.png)
can anyone quivk help
i want to run the comamnd: but thisassertion erro again and again and im much fratrated with it.
